# User defined function call on useEffect not rerturing correct output

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state, tic-tac-toe

I'm building an tic-tac-toe app in **React JS**, but useEffect in react behaving pretty weired for me.
this is full project url: https://github.com/vyshnav4u/react-tic-tac-toe

**Snippet Having problem**

You can see that i'm calling **isWinner** function inside useEffect, in winning condition is meet, isWinner should be print **"finish"** on console and return true. Now it's printing "finish" on console correctly but not return or printing true inside useEffect.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (currentSquare >= 0) {
      let winFlag = isWinner(currentSquare);

      // this should print true when winning condition is meet,
      // but it's always printing false
      console.log(winFlag);
      if (winFlag) {
        alert("won");
      }
    }
  }, [currentSquare, value]);

//isWinner function
const isWinner = (currentIndex) => {
    pattern.forEach((singlePattern, index) => {
      if (singlePattern.includes(currentIndex)) {
        let tempIndex_0 = singlePattern[0];
        let tempIndex_1 = singlePattern[1];
        let tempIndex_2 = singlePattern[2];

        if (
          value[tempIndex_0] == value[tempIndex_1] &&
          value[tempIndex_1] == value[tempIndex_2]
        ) {
          console.log("finish");
          return true;
        }
      }
    });
    return false;
  };
```

**Edit:**
The issue was sorted, it was **not a problem caused by useEffect** but with the incorrect use of forEach in *isWinner* function please see the verified answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array.prototype.forEach` is a void return. The `return true` isn't a return for the `isWinner` callback, it's only a return for the `.forEach` callback.

If I'm understanding the purpose of the `isWinner` function you want to return true|false if the wining condition is met or not.

You could keep an `isWon` variable initialized false and only set true upon the condition.

```
const isWinner = (currentIndex) => {
  let isWon = false;

  pattern.forEach((singlePattern, index) => {
    if (singlePattern.includes(currentIndex)) {
      const tempIndex_0 = singlePattern[0];
      const tempIndex_1 = singlePattern[1];
      const tempIndex_2 = singlePattern[2];

      if (
        value[tempIndex_0] == value[tempIndex_1] &&
        value[tempIndex_1] == value[tempIndex_2]
      ) {
        console.log("finish");
        isWon = true;
      }
    }
  });
  return isWon;
};
```

Or refactor the code to be a little more functional.

```
const isWinner = (currentIndex) => {
  return pattern.some((singlePattern, index) => {
    if (singlePattern.includes(currentIndex)) {
      const [tempIndex_0, tempIndex_1, tempIndex_2] = singlePattern;

      if (
        value[tempIndex_0] == value[tempIndex_1] &&
        value[tempIndex_1] == value[tempIndex_2]
      ) {
        console.log("finish");
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're returning within the callback of the `forEach`. The loop will break. However, you will still go to the next line in the `isWinner` function and return false.

Putting a console.log right before `return false;` will show you this.